# How to get distinct values of afeild in ES?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to calculate distinct values of a field in ES. For example if I have an index containing documents like:

```
{
    "NAME": "XYZ",
    "TITLE": "ABC"
}

{
    "NAME": "RTY",
    "TITLE": "BNM"
}
```

I want to have an output like this:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 10000,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "record_new",
        "_type": "record_new",
        "_id": "AWChga1952qKS23vpN8J",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
        "TITLE":{
            "ABC",
            "BNM"
            }
        }
    }]
    }
}
```

How can I get the distinct values in "title" field in this format. I have tried using aggregation but the output is very weired. Please help.

Comment: This is the query using aggregation I used but the result is weired.

GET record_new/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs" : {
  "uniq_soft_tags" : {
  "terms" : { 
    "field" : "title",
    "size": 1000
    }
  }
}
}

Comment: If is fine to add comments but you could edit the question itself to add more details.

Comment: Could you share the Elasticsearch version that you are working with please?

Comment: @RajindRuparathna version is 5.3.2

Comment: @RajindRuparathna I would like to add that the the above aggregate query is splitting up a single value in TITLE field also, i.e. if suppose the TITLE field has value "Windows Server", so in the output it shows 2 different keys Windows and Server

Comment: Do you use a mapping with this data?

Answer (score 1):

**Test Data:**

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/stackoverflow/os/1
{
    "NAME": "XYZ",
    "TITLE": "LINUX OS"
}

PUT http://localhost:9200/stackoverflow/os/1
{
    "NAME": "XYZ",
    "TITLE": "WINDOWS SERVER"
}
```

**First Query Attempt:**

Note I have used POST here instead of GET since most REST clients do not support payload with GET.

```
POST http://localhost:9200/stackoverflow/_search
{
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{
      "uniq_soft_tags":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"TITLE"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If you did not give a mapping for your data and run the above, most probably you'll end up with below error.

```
Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [TITLE] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory
```

Read more about that [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html#_fielddata_is_disabled_on_literal_text_literal_fields_by_default).

Adding the mapping to enable Fielddata:

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/stackoverflow/_mapping/os/
{
  "properties": {
    "TITLE": { 
      "type":     "text",
      "fielddata": true
    }
  }
}
```

**Second Query Attempt:**

```
POST http://localhost:9200/stackoverflow/_search
{
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{
      "uniq_soft_tags":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"TITLE"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Results:**

```
{
    "took": 10,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 2,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "uniq_soft_tags": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "linux",
                    "doc_count": 1
                },
                {
                    "key": "os",
                    "doc_count": 1
                },
                {
                    "key": "server",
                    "doc_count": 1
                },
                {
                    "key": "windows",
                    "doc_count": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the doc_counts here are approximate.

Make sure to read the following section in the docs. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html#before-enabling-fielddata

That explains how you get that spilitting behaviour.

> **Before enabling fielddata**
>
> Before you enable fielddata, consider why you are using a text field
>   for aggregations, sorting, or in a script. It usually doesn’t make
>   sense to do so.
>
> A text field is analyzed before indexing so that a value like New York
>   can be found by searching for new or for york. A terms aggregation on
>   this field will return a new bucket and a york bucket, when you
>   probably want a single bucket called New York.

**UPDATE:**

To prevent splitting behaviour you have to provide a mapping as follows. Note that with this you would not need the previous mapping where we set Fielddata to true.

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/stackoverflow/_mapping/os/
{
  "properties": {
    "TITLE": { 
      "type":     "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": { 
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now we can use,
**TITLE** field for searches.
**TITLE.keyword** field for aggregations, sorting, or in scripts.

**Third Query Attempt:**

```
POST http://localhost:9200/stackoverflow/_search
{
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{
      "uniq_soft_tags":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"TITLE.keyword"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Results:**

```
{
    "took": 59,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 2,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "uniq_soft_tags": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "LINUX OS",
                    "doc_count": 1
                },
                {
                    "key": "WINDOWS SERVER",
                    "doc_count": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the value in the field is getting split based on space character. I do not want that. Is there a way through which that can be prevented. The desired output something like :
"buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "Linux os",
                    "doc_count": 1
                },
                {
                    "key": "Windows Server",
                    "doc_count": 1
                },

Comment: @aman Were you able to give it a try with the updated solution?

Comment: Yes that helped.Thanks. But I am now in a different issue regarding the same thing.

Comment: @aman I would be glad to help you on that in a new question. :-)